# How to integrate third party api's in Django?

Tags: python, django, logging, integrate

I have a project that works as a single login and I must integrate other apis so that they can log in to this api and return to their logged-in api of origin.

Any help or information on the subject will be appreciated.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1):

You can do achieve that in the below manner

```
domain = request.META['HTTP_HOST']
API = {your_API}
data = {Data that you want to post}
r = request.post(url=API, data=data)
resp = r.json()
```

In "resp" you will get your data that is returned from API.
I hope this helps.

Comment: That `domain` variable isn't even used here.

Comment: Yes, domain is not used here. But it shall work without this also.